# xampp v3.3.0 con php 8.0.5 agregar php 7.4 desde Windows10

Tags: php, xampp, cakephp

Hice un proyecto en php con el xampp 3.3.0 que trae php 8.0.5 . Necesito correr unas pruebas con 1 proyecto que tiene php 7.4 . He investigado y probado variantes, pero no he encontrado un downgrade desde php 8. Una de las complicaciones es que lei que hay que bajar la version de php, por ejemplo php7.4, y agregar en el httpd.conf la línea  LoadModule php7_module c:\php7\libphp7.so ... pero en el php 8 no está esa línea. Alguien me puede ayudar a levantar desde el xampp 3.3.0 , la version que necesito, entre php 8.0.5 y la 7.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el siguiente enlace tendrás acceso a todas las versiones de [xammp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/) disponibles... Incluso, algunas de las versiones anteriores para que puedas hacer downgrade.